# How to get count of applications and application names from BizTalk server?

Tags: sql, count, biztalk

I would like to generate a monthly report from BizTalk Server

How to get number of applications and application name in a BizTalk server?

Please provide SQL or WMI query to get this information from the Biztalk server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could just run to get a list of application with name.

```
use BizTalkMgmtDb
select * from dbo.bts_application
```

I do however think that running directly against the database isn't the best way to go, as things in the db structure might change etc it's better to use the API provided in the [ExplorerOM dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.explorerom%28v=bts.80%29.aspx).

One way to use the API is of course using .NET directly but a more suitable way for you need are probably to use the [PowerShell Providers for BizTalk](http://psbiztalk.codeplex.com/) that use ExplorerOM but exposes it's functionally via PowerShell and a command windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BTSTask ListApps Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560942.aspx)

```
BTSTask ListApps > c:\path\file.txt
```